# AccessViolationException - Tentativa de leitura ou gravação em memória protegida

Tags: c#, opencv

Estou trabalhando com o **OPENCVSHARP** (OpenCV) para acessar uma câmera **Ps3Eye** (Câmera do playstation 3) em C#.

Porém estou tendo um problema sério de memória protegida! Uso o visual studio 2010 no Windows7.

[image: Print do erro]

Código:

```
    IntPtr _ptr;
    public IntPtr _ptrBmpPixels;
    static IntPtr _camera;
    static int w = 0, h = 0;

    public void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _camera = CLEyeCreateCamera(CameraUUID(0), CLEyeCameraColorMode.CLEYE_COLOR_RAW, CLEyeCameraResolution.CLEYE_VGA, 75);
        CLEyeCameraGetFrameDimensions(_camera, ref w, ref h);
        CLEyeCameraStart(_camera);
        _ptrBmpPixels = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(w * h * 4);
        RtlZeroMemory(_ptrBmpPixels, w * h * 4);
        Bitmap bmpGraph = new Bitmap(w, h, w * 4, PixelFormat.Format32bppRgb, _ptrBmpPixels);
        pictureBox2.Image = bmpGraph;
        myTimer2.Enabled = true;
    }

   public void timer2(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {      
     CvInvoke.cvQueryFrame(_camera);// AQUI ESTÁ O ERRO ao ACESSAR O "_camera"

        CLEyeCameraGetFrame( _camera,_ptrBmpPixels,500);
        pictureBox2.Invalidate();  
        //IntPtr img = CvInvoke.cvQueryFrame(_ptrBmpPixels);        
        //IplImage iplImage = (IplImage)Marshal.PtrToStructure(img, typeof(IplImage));           
        Bitmap bmpGraph = new Bitmap (160, 480, 640, PixelFormat.Format32bppRgb, _ptrBmpPixels);    
        IplImage mp = Cv.CreateImage(Cv.Size(bmpGraph.Width, bmpGraph.Height), BitDepth.U8, 3);
        //learn(mp, bmpGraph);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Existe mais de um problema no seu código e vou apontar alguns deles para você. Apesar do erro acontecer naquela linha, o problema provavelmente está nas instruções que são executadas antes disso.

É importante perceber que `CLEyeCreateCamera()` e outros métodos podem falhar. Portanto é extremamente essencial **codificar de forma defensiva**, e testar o retorno desses métodos:

```
_camera = CLEyeCreateCamera(CameraUUID(0), CLEyeCameraColorMode.CLEYE_COLOR_RAW,CLEyeCameraResolution.CLEYE_VGA, 75);
if (!_camera) {
    // Falhou, imprimir erro na tela
}
```

Outro método que pode falhar é `CLEyeCameraStart()`, e por isso você deveria executar algo como:

```
 bool success = CLEyeCameraStart(_camera);
 if (!success) {
     // Falhou, imprimir erro na tela
 }
```

E assim por diante.

Outra coisa, `CvInvoke.cvQueryFrame()` espera receber um objeto do tipo `Capture`, mas você está passando um `IntPtr` pra ele, e isso não faz sentido algum.

O problema principal é que você está confundindo a API do **CL-Eye** com a API do **OpenCV**, cuidado.

Answer (score 0):

Essa comunicação entre programas de memória gerenciada e não gerenciada pode ser complicado. E como trabalha com ponteiro no lugar de objetos, então, meio que tudo pode acontecer.

Não conheço essa biblioteca OPENCVSHARP, mas como usa IntPtr então sei que é um ponteiro em "C" ou "C++". Acho que o problema de violação pode ser que o parâmetro passado não é bem do tipo esperado. É como você estivesse passando um parâmetro do tipo string em um método que espera um int, como é um ponteiro, ele pode ser um ponteiro de qualquer coisa.

Procurei uma chamada parecida em C, e achei um código que usa esses dois métodos:

- CLEyeCreateCamera
- cvQueryFrame

E a chamada do cvQueryFrame não recebe uma camera, mas sim um 'capture', que aparentemente é obtida de um método chamado "cvCaptureFromCAM" passando o ID da camera. Segue o código, talvez te ajude a resolver esse problema:

https://code.google.com/p/moveonpc/source/browse/src/tracker/camera_control.c?r=431e30226184846a5fe49823606b53a2a212c895

- CLEyeCreateCamera - Linha 56
- cvQueryFrame - Linha 129
- cvCaptureFromCAM - Linha 67